# process.hrtime returns non matching second and milisecond

Tags: node.js

I use process.hrtime() to calculate the time a process takes in sec and millisec as follows:

```
router.post(
  "/api/result-store/v1/indexing-analyzer/:searchID/:id",
  async (req, res) => {

    var hrstart = process.hrtime();

    //some code which takes time

    hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
    console.info("Execution time (hr): %ds %dms", hrend[0], hrend[1] / 1000000);

  }
);
```

I followed the following for code:

https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/measure-execution-time-nodejs-javascript/

So I expect to get a matching time in millisec and sec but here is what I get:

```
Execution time (hr): 54s 105.970357ms
```

So this is very strange since when I convert 54s to millisec I get this 54000 so I do not get where this  "105.970357ms" comes from. Is there anything wrong with my code? why do I see this mismatch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [`process.hrtime()` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time) it returns an array `[seconds, nanoseconds]`, **where `nanoseconds` is the remaining part** of the real time that can't be represented in second precision.

1 nanosecond = 10^9 seconds

1 millisecond = 10^6 nanoseconds

In your case the execution took `54 seconds and 105.970357 milliseconds` or 
`54000 milliseconds + 105.970357 milliseconds`.

Or if you need it in seconds: `(hrend[0]+ hrend[1] / Math.pow(10,9))`